# Layout Builder.

Tags: pages

I recently bought a theme from Theme forest called Enfold: http://www.kriesi.at/themedemo/?theme=enfold

The pages have an "Advanced layout" building that lets you build you content how you need. I found some plugins like http://wordpress.org/plugins/page-layout-builder/

that are similar, ie, based on modules like accordion, tab, header, icon list etc that you can use to mold your content.

I am really really curious how one would go about creating your own layout builder. IE, is it just an api/interface for shortcodes? I could not find any resources/tutorials so any help in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: Look up the code of the theme you bought?

Comment: yeah I have and am still going through it. It's just really complex and broken out.

Comment: Am thinking so far it's just API for shortcodes.